# Stopwatch shows different time on local than on deployed

Tags: c#, async-await, .net-6.0

I am struggling with different time when i invoke request locally, and when i invoke on deployed application. I cannot show my full code, but schema looks like this:

```
[Controller]
class MyControllerClass{
Service myService = new Service();

[GET]
public Stream DownloadFile(string binID, Stopwatch stopwatch, out XciFileInfo fileInfo)
        {
            var url = GetFileUrl(binID);
            var findResult = webDavClient.Propfind(url).GetAwaiter().GetResult();            
            return webDavClient.GetStreamAsync(url,stopwatch).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

}
```

```
class Service{

public async Task<ProxyStream> GetStreamAsync(Uri requestUri)
        {
            var requestStopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var connectionStopwatch= Stopwatch.StartNew();

            connectionStopwatch.Start();
            requestStopwatch.Start();
            var meth = () => GetProxyStreamTask(requestUri, requestStopwatch);
            var res =  await FireMethod(meth);
            connectionStopwatch.Stop();
   
            return res;
        }

private async Task<ProxyStream> GetProxyStreamTask(Uri requestUri, Stopwatch stopwatch)
        {
            var stream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(requestUri);

            return new ProxyStream(stream, stopwatch,
                "MethodTag", requestUri);
        }

private async Task<T> FireMethod<T>(Func<Task<T>> func)
        {                
            return await func();
        }

}
```

and my ProxyStream implementation:

```
public class ProxyStream : Stream
{

        public ProxyStream(Stream stream,Stopwatch stopwatch,
                string tag, URI requestUri)
        {
        this.stream = stream;
        this.stopwatch = stopwatch;
        this.uri= uri;
        this.methodTag = tag;
        } 

        public override bool CanRead => stream.CanRead;

        public override bool CanSeek => stream.CanSeek;

        public override bool CanWrite => stream.CanWrite;

        public override long Length => stream.Length;

        public override long Position { get => stream.Position; set => stream.Position = value; }

        public double ElapsedTime { get; private set; }

        public override void Flush()
        {
            stream.Flush();
        }

        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            var res = stream.Read(buffer, offset, count);

            if(res < 1 )
            {
                //here getting time
                //do sth with elapsed time
                //There is a "bug"

            }
            return res;
        }

        public double GetElapsedTime()
        {
            return this.ElapsedTime;
        }

        public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
        {
            return stream.Seek(offset, origin);
        }

        public override void SetLength(long value)
        {
            stream.SetLength(value);
        }

        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            stream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
        }
}
```

If i catch in debug (or just print on console) time from:

```
if(res < 1 )
            {
                var elapsedTime = stopwatch.Elapsed.Miliseconds;
                //do sth with elapsed time
                //There is a "bug"

            }
```

it's different depends if i run local (takes like 5 seconds) or if i run it on deployed app (it "takes" 0,2s or 0,05s or sth like that - too short). Postman in both scenarios shows 5-6seconds (time of communication + generate request + time of reading of stream).
Where is bug in my measurement? I need to have that time.

I think the main factor can be in `var stream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(requestUri);` but i am not sure. Maybe CLR waits for that method  in different places in code? Let's suppose CLR waits for it locally where Read method in ProxyStream is called, and on deployed app CLR wait where `await` is? I have no idea.

Comment: A stopwatch just measures the time between two instances. If the times are different then it is probably because different amount of time did passed. This may be due to differences in environment (debug/release), hardware, compilation times, or some bug in the code. There is no way to tell what the issue is without more information. Use a profiler to see what actually takes time.

Comment: @JonasH - i know how it works. The question is if "await" makes any difference here, and  how to deal with it. Everything would be ok if longer time be at deployed app, but on deployed one time is like 0,2s, and on local instance i have few seconds what has no any sense.

Comment: If it's `ElapsedTime` you're comparing, your `+=` logic is not correct, as for each call to `Read()` you're adding the total elapsed time since the stopwatch was started.
If the stream is read in one chunk, you'll get lucky.  If it's 50 chunks, it could be wildly out.

Then you're stopping your stopwatch after you've _created_ the stream, not after you've _read_ it.

Also your shown usage does not match the shown `GetStreamAsync()` implementation, so we can't really see what else might be going on.

`await` should not make any significant difference here.

Comment: @sellotape Where I am stopping my stopwatch after creating stream? In higher level there are 2 stopwatches - for request and "connection"
That ```+=``` operated on third stopwatch I deleted from example. Inside ProxyStream we are operating only on that I passed.

Comment: You've edited the question sufficiently that some of my comments no longer apply.  We still can't see how `Service.GetStreamAsync()` is actually called.  Create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - even if it produces only one set of timing results - so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Things like `await` will have some overhead. But it should be measured in *microseconds*. If you have differences in *seconds* there is something else going on. Maybe some startup cost that is not visible in prod? Maybe some network timeout? Something else? Whatever the case, I would look more at external factors than the code. Testing on a few more system and trying to find common denominators are often a good strategy.